# How to adjust table cell size to clipped image content

Tags: html, css

I have this image which contains four logos and I want to clip the logos and display them in individual table cells:

[image: logos]

The problem is that the `td` size seems to be adjusted to the original image, not the size of the clipped logos. I tried inserting position, overflow, inside all classes of the CSS and nothing works.

This is the live code of my work:

```css
img {
    max-width:160px;
    max-height: 160px;
    content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/SArYJ.png");
}

.windows {
    clip-path: inset(0px 80px 80px 0px);
}
.android {
    clip-path: inset(80px 0px 0px 80px);
}

table, th, td {
    border:  1px solid black;
}

td {
    background: #17f129;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Windows Download</td>
        <td><img src="" class="windows" alt="windows logo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Android Download</td>
        <td><img src="" class="android" alt="android logo"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround where you don't need to split up the image in multiple separate images is to transform and scale the clipped images to make each logo fit in the center with an appropriate size:

```css
img {
    max-width: 160px;
    max-height: 160px;
    content: url("https://i.imgur.com/uFtuNXE.png");
  }

  .windows {
    clip-path: inset(0px 80px 80px 0px);
    transform: translate(60px, 60px) scale(1.5);
  }
  .android {
    clip-path: inset(80px 0px 0px 80px);
    transform: translate(-60px, -60px) scale(1.5);
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  td {
    background: #17f129;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Windows Download</td>
        <td><img src="" class="windows" alt="windows logo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Android Download</td>
        <td><img src="" class="android" alt="android logo"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's take one of your clip paths as an example to explain the idea above:

```
clip-path: inset(0px 80px 80px 0px)
```

If you set `overflow: hidden` on the `td`, you can center the clipped logo like this:

```
transform: translate(60px, 60px) scale(1.5);
```

The reason why I translate by `60px, 60px` in this example is because:

```
80 * 1.5 = 120
and 120 / 2 = 60
```

So if you apply this idea you will always end up in the middle. You do need to account for which direction you're translating in.

Answer (score 0):

Try cropping the one big image from imgur.com into two smaller images, like:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7W9x.png  (Windows Pic)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Owa.png  (Android Pic)
```

And then edit your CSS code to something like:

```
    imgWin {
        max-width : 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        padding: 10px;
        content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7W9x.png");
    }
    
    imgAnd {
        max-width : 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        padding: 10px;
        content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Owa.png");
    }
    
    table, th, td {
        border:  1px solid black;
    }
    
    td {
        background: #17f129;
    }
```

And then edit your HTML code to something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Windows Download</td>
        <td><imgWin src=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Android Download</td>
        <td><imgAnd src=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
    imgWin {
        max-width : 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        padding: 10px;
        content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7W9x.png");
    }
    
    imgAnd {
        max-width : 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        padding: 10px;
        content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Owa.png");
    }
    
    table, th, td {
        border:  1px solid black;
    }
    
    td {
        background: #17f129;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Windows Download</td>
        <td><imgWin src=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Android Download</td>
        <td><imgAnd src=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer my problem, but this is not the solution because I use multiples images that have inside multiples sub images, like the image example of system logos. The ability of having multiple images in one image is the portability to load 1 image and use like assets in the all project, but I appreciate your goal, thanks very much!.